# ignoring command exit code in linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a Postgres console command `createdb appname_production_master`, which return error exit code if the database with this name already exists.

Is it possible to make this command do not return any exit code?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just ignore the exit code, for example like this.

```
createdb appname_production_master || true
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this doesn't ignore the exit code, but it uses it in an expression that always succeeds.

Comment: "<<command>> || :" is another form that seems to work, where the colon is the null command that always succeeds

Answer (score 1):

Unix commands always return exit codes, but you need not respond to the exit code.

When you run a command `$?` is set to the exit code of the process. As this happens for every command, simply running a different command after the first will change `$?`.

For example:

```
createdb appname_production_master # returns 1, a failure code
# $? is 1
/bin/true # always returns 0, success
# $? is 0
```

Here's another example:

```
/bin/false # returns false, I assume usually 1
echo $? # outputs 1
echo $? # outputs 0, last echo command succeeded
```